# Info About messages.phtml in 2.4.4 version

Tags: magento2.4, success-message

Hello i'm doing some debug for an issue i have and i made an override of messages.phtml to following path
/app/design/frontend/Company/template_child/Magento_Theme/templates/messages.phtml
inside messages.phtml file there is following script

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

Now someone is able to tell me where is following path? "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"

I already tried following
/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js
but is not there..

Thanks

Comment: vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js

Comment: If Magento is installed using composer then it is in the vendor folder and if Magento is installed from GitHub then it is in the app/code folder

Answer (score 0):

Try there:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js